# Sending messages via LLRP

Tags: node.js, rfid, llrp

Does anyone have experience with LLRP? I found two modules on npm (and [modified one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/llrp) to get more data out of it), but I have no idea how to actually *send* messages to my Impinj reader.

I understand this may be a niche issue but hey, you never know who knows what.

Comment: What are the kind of messages you want to send to the reader? If you can be a bit more verbose on what you try to achieve, I can try helping you out.

Comment: @Danny I want to be able to send message constants like GET_READER_CAPABILITIES and parameter constants like ChannelIndex. Forgive me if I'm saying things incorrectly, I'm pretty new to this!

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/itemsense-node

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nsqjs

Comment: try these two module may help you 
update me if not :)

Comment: @Adil Itemsense would require me to be locked into Impinj's software which isn't such a bad thing but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

I have been trying with motorola equipment recently and as per my understanding the library which you mentioned(https://github.com/GeenenTijd/llrp-nodejs) is the only one latest package available.

Try to check the source code in (LLRPMain.js) which is understandable and you could tweak it further by using network sniffers like 'wireshark' and understand the communication from both sides. This approach helped me.

Hope this would be useful and please let me know your progress.

Answer (score 0):

Before sending messages to a reader parameters should be fitted and encoding  should be done according to [llrp](https://www.gs1.org/standards/epc-rfid/llrp/1-1-0) protocol.

An example can be found in a [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/llrp-ts) in file https://github.com/YaroslavSl/llrp-ts/blob/master/src/getLlrpMessage.ts

Also [wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) and [Impinj ItemTest](https://support.impinj.com/hc/en-us/articles/204059593-Impinj-ItemTest-Software) help to understand the llrp protocol communication.